# Split a data frame string based on a \

Tags: r, string, tidyr

I am trying to split a string column in my data frame into two different columns based on a . My data looks as such :

```
     Rk Player  Season   Age Tm    Lg       WS     G    GS    MP    FG   FGA  `2P` `2PA`  `3P` `3PA`    FT   FTA   ORB   DRB   TRB   AST   STL   BLK   TOV    PF
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 "LeBro~ 2010-~    26 MIA   NBA    15.6    79    79  3063   758  1485   666  1206    92   279   503   663    80   510   590   554   124    50   284   163
2     2 "Pau G~ 2010-~    30 LAL   NBA    14.7    82    82  3037   593  1120   592  1117     1     3   354   430   268   568   836   273    48   130   142   203
```

The column I have tried to manipulate is the 'Player' column. The entries for that column look like such.

```
"LeBron James\\jamesle01"        "Pau Gasol\\gasolpa01"           "Dwight Howard\\howardw01"
```

I want it split into two columns pName and pID

```
pName            pID

LeBron James    jamesle01
Pau Gasol       gasolpa01
Dwight Howard   howardw01
```

I have tried using `gsub`, `sub`, `str_replace`, and `separate` and have not been able to figure it out

```
player_stats2010 %>%
+   str_replace(Player,"\\\.*","")
```

```
player_stats2010 %>%
+   sub("\\\", "", player_stats2010$Player)
```

```
player_stats2010 %>%
+   sub("\.*", "", player_stats2010$Player)
```

```
player_stats2010 %>%
+   gsub("\.*", "", player_stats2010$Player)
```

```
player_stats2010_test <- player_salaries_2010 %>%
+   separate(Player, c("pName", "pID"), "\")
```

I really do not understand the syntax for this question despite looking online and at several other questions. If you could please help me understand what I do not understand, that would be awesome. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Maybe `strsplit(x, "\\", fixed = TRUE)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) read.table** Using `x` from the Note at the end and only base R use `read.table` as shown:

```
read.table(text = x, sep = "\\", col.names = c("pName", "pID"))
```

giving:

```
          pName       pID
1  LeBron James jamesle01
2     Pau Gasol gasolpa01
3 Dwight Howard howardw01
```

**2) tidyr**

With tidyr we could do this:

```
library(tidyr)
data.frame(x) %>%
  separate(x, c("pName", "pID"), sep = r"{\\}")
```

### Note

The input is assumed to be:

```
x <- c("LeBron James\\jamesle01", "Pau Gasol\\gasolpa01", "Dwight Howard\\howardw01")
```

Comment: Just a note that `r"{\\}"` requires R version 4.0.0 or higher. A lot of people are still on versions prior to that unfortunately.

Comment: UIse "\\\\" if your R version does not support r"{..}"

Comment: Thank you very much this worked. Could you perhaps explain what `sep = r"{\\}"` does and why it is not just `sep = "\\" `?

Comment: If you use "..." then the quoting will remove one level of backslashes and then the regular expression removes a second so to specify a regular expression containing a single backslash requires that you double it for the quoting and then double it again for the regular expression.  If you use r"{...}" then backslashes are not special for the quoting but still need to be doubled for the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_extract`from the package `stringr` as well as character classes that do not include `\\`:

```
library(stringr)
player_stats$pName <- str_extract(player_stats$Player, "^[\\w\\s]+")
player_stats$pID <- str_extract(player_stats$Player, "[\\w\\s]+$")
```

In both cases you define a character class allowing only letters (`\\w`) and whitespace chars (`\\s`) to occur, the difference between the two variables being that `pName` looks for that pattern from the string beginning (`^`) while `pID` looks for it from the end of the string (`$`).

Result:

```
player_stats
                    Player         pName       pID
1  LeBron James\\jamesle01  LeBron James jamesle01
2     Pau Gasol\\gasolpa01     Pau Gasol gasolpa01
3 Dwight Howard\\howardw01 Dwight Howard howardw01
```

Data:

```
player_stats <- data.frame(
  Player = c("LeBron James\\jamesle01", "Pau Gasol\\gasolpa01", "Dwight Howard\\howardw01"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation!